# How to display more than one image in an <input type="text">

Tags: html, css

I have am `<input type="text">` using

```
background: #e3e3e6 url(search.jpg) no-repeat 7px 2px;
```

on the left side.

I want to add an other image on the other side of the text box. (right side). 
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Use `:before` and `:after` css pseudo-class

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: you may also just use [multiple background images on the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

Comment: @Justinas, native elements like `input` don't have `:before` and `:after`

Comment: @NicoO, that sounds like it solves the issue, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Victor you are right, just placed an answer. Good catch about the pseudo elements on input fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [multiple background images on the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds), just like this:

html (use the class attribute to seperate the elements with and without backgrounds)

```
<input type="text" />
```

Sample CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    background: url(http://www.placehold.it/20x20&text=left), url(http://www.placehold.it/20x20&text=right);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center left, center right;
}
```

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oLd7zdf7/**